# How can I execute different methods on different intervals of time with the same timer

Tags: c#

I used timer.elapsed but this one just can call methods with the same interval of time for example

```
timer.interval = 1000;
timer.elapsed += first();
timer.elapsed+=  second();
```

this call first and second every 1 second and i need call one at 3 seconds and the other at 5 seconds.

Comment: The obvious answer is to use two timers.  Can you explain why you need to use the same timer?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use multiple timers.

```
 timer1.Inverval = 3000;
 timer1.Elapsed += first();

 timer2.Interval = 5000;
 timer2.Elapsed += second();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The question explicitly asks how to do it using the same timer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really cannot add multiple timers, (why not?) just calculate the greatest common divisor (GCD) of both intervals (say if one function needs to execute every 30 seconds, and one needs to execute every 45 seconds, then the GCD is five seconds, so set the timer to trigger every five seconds, but execute FunctionA every 6th time the timer kicks off, and functionB every 9th time.

Comment: So, if one method is to be invoked every 998 milliseconds, and the other is to be invoked every 999 milliseconds, we are going to have a timer firing a thousand times a second, of which 998 times we will be doing nothing.  That's not very cool.

Comment: What do you mean "doing nothing"? what do you think is doing the timing? a magical imp?

Comment: Charles, the timing is done by hardware, without requiring the CPU clock to be ON. When a timer fires, the hardware issues an interrupt and causes the CPU clock to start so that the CPU may service the interrupt. Your solution under the scenario that I suggested will essentially be keeping the CPU fully powered all the time for no good reason, because starting the clock every millisecond is practically as good as keeping it on all the time. Look at my answer for a solution which allows the clock to be mostly stopped and only forces it on when it is actually time to invoke one of the functions.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, (which is a computer sitting idle, doing nothing,) a modern computer is in "Stop Clock" mode most of the time, and if I remember correctly, a Windows PC that does not have anything else to do only goes out of Stop Clock once every 50 milliseconds or so.  This number is probably higher on other architectures.  Your timer scheme would be forcing the computer to go out of Stop Clock once every millisecond only to find out that it has nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to do it using just a single timer:

You will need to maintain a list in which each entry contains a reference to the method to call, and the time at which it should be invoked.  (Must use absolute time values for this, not intervals.)

1. Walk through the list, find the entry with the smallest time value, (the time that is closest to now,) and set the timer to fire at that point in time.
2. When the timer fires, walk through the list again, and invoke any methods whose time-to-invoke is less-than-or-equal to now.  For each method invoked, calculate the next time-to-invoke that method.
3. Go to step 1.

In doing so, you will essentially be re-implementing the timer mechanism of the .Net runtime, which is an exercise in futility.  So, you would be much better off ***not*** doing it this way, and using multiple timers instead.

Comment: +1 This is how `System.Threading.Timer` works under the hood. Which is also one of the reasons why OP is reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you'd want to do this, but you *could* do something similar to the following:

```
public class MultiIntervalTimer: IDisposable
{
    private readonly Timer innerTimer;
    private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<int, MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo> callbackInfos;
    private long totalElapsedMiliseconds;
    private readonly int innerTimerInterval;
    private object syncRoot = new object();
    private bool disposed;

    public MultiIntervalTimer(Dictionary<int, MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo> callbacks, int dueTime)
    {
        if (callbacks == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callbacks));

        var innerTimerCallback = new TimerCallback(innerCallback);
        callbackInfos = new Dictionary<int, MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo>(callbacks);
        innerTimerInterval = getGreatestCommonDivisor(callbacks.Keys);
        innerTimer = new Timer(innerTimerCallback, null, dueTime, innerTimerInterval);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        innerTimer.Dispose();
        disposed = true;
    }

    private static int getGreatestCommonDivisor(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        Debug.Assert(numbers != null);
        Debug.Assert(numbers.Any());
        var numbersArray = numbers.ToArray();

        if (numbersArray.Length == 1)
            return numbersArray[0];

        if (numbersArray.Length == 2)
            return getGreatestCommonDivisor(numbersArray[0], numbersArray[1]);

        var trimmedNumbersArray = new int[numbersArray.Length - 1];
        Array.Copy(numbersArray, 1, trimmedNumbersArray, 0, trimmedNumbersArray.Length);
        return getGreatestCommonDivisor(numbersArray[0], getGreatestCommonDivisor(trimmedNumbersArray));
    }

    private static int getGreatestCommonDivisor(int left, int right)
    {
        while (right != 0)
        {
            var temp = right;
            right = left % right;
            left = temp;
        }

        return left;
    }

    private void innerCallback(object state)
    {
        Debug.Assert(syncRoot != null);
        Debug.Assert(!disposed);
        var elapsed = 0L;

        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            totalElapsedMiliseconds += innerTimerInterval;
            elapsed = totalElapsedMiliseconds;
        }

        foreach (var callback in callbackInfos.Where(c => elapsed % c.Key == 0))
        {
            callback.Value?.Callback(callback.Value.State);
        }
    }
}

public class MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo
{
    public MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo(TimerCallback callback, object state)
    {
        if (callback == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback));

        Callback = callback;
        State = state;
    }

    public TimerCallback Callback { get; }
    public object State { get; }
}
```

And a way to use it:

```
public class State
{
    public State()
        :this(0)
    { }

    private State(int count)
    {
        Count = count;
    }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void IncrementCount() => Count++;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var state = new State();
    bool stop = false;
    var intervalCallback1 = new MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(c =>
                                                                                                  {
                                                                                                      Console.WriteLine($"Interval 1: Call #{state.Count}. Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                                                                                                      state.IncrementCount();
                                                                                                  }), state);

    var intervalCallback2 = new MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(c =>
                                                                                                  {
                                                                                                      Console.WriteLine($"Interval 2: Call #{state.Count}. Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                                                                                                      state.IncrementCount();
                                                                                                  }), state);
    var intervalCallback3 = new MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(c =>
                                                                                                  {
                                                                                                      Console.WriteLine($"Interval 3: Call #{state.Count}. Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                                                                                                      state.IncrementCount();
                                                                                                  }), state);
    var intervalCallback4 = new MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(c =>
                                                                                                  {
                                                                                                      Console.WriteLine($"Interval 4: Call #{state.Count}.  Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}.\r\n Exiting loop", state);
                                                                                                      stop = true;
                                                                                                  }), state);

    var callbacks = new Dictionary<int, MultiIntervalTimerCallbackInfo>() { { 50, intervalCallback1 },
                                                                            { 100, intervalCallback2 },
                                                                            { 200, intervalCallback3  },
                                                                            { 2000, intervalCallback4 } };

    using (var timer = new MultiIntervalTimer(callbacks, 1000))
    {
        while (!stop)
        {

        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Total calls: {state.Count}.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I've barely tested this and I haven't spent too much time thinking about all the implications of the multithreading going on and the required locking / synchronisation, so take this code as a very preliminary approach.